# How to design Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android

How to design toolbar as it contain image then afte title and when it expand the image will go to top center and title below it .
For example goole play store profile view there is a link also that describe it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIbx2wZmA7M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch this [CoordinatorBehaviorExample example](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample) and modify to your liking.

This is the example : https://i.imgur.com/fEhmLKW.mp4

Comment: can i design a card view with holding image in center top